# crystal reports Summarising field in group header has duplicated value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to summarise (sum) a field in a group header and the value is being multiplied by the number of details lines within the group.

The structure of my data is the following tables-

```
Branch
    Job
        Invoice
             InvoiceLineItem
```

and my report groups follow the same pattern, with the invoice line item being the detail line

So I can include a summary of any of the InvoiceLineItem fields in the group header and this works as expected.

What I want is to include a summary of a field from the invoice table, for instance "NumberofDaystoDeliver" in all the group headers. So in the Invoice group header, its simple, i just put the Invoice.NumberofDaystoDeliver field there. 
But when I create a summary in the Job and Branch groups the Invoice.NumberofDaystoDeliver field is summed for each detail line which can be a varying number.

I know I can use Running Totals in the footer but is there any way to do this in the headers?

Thanks